# Error: Failed to lookup view "form" in views directory "./views"

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

i have made the handlebars template config on my app.js file, but when i try to run my code with nodemon he returns me this error. anyone can help?
This error was generated when I was trying to resolve the "handlebars is not a function" error and I couldn't resolve it

[main_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdSHe.png)
[main_handlebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG3Vt.png)
[form_handlebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV1ta.png)

Comment: You'll need to share the problematic code.

Comment: Please [post code instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). It looks like your `form.handlebars` is inside the `views/layouts/` directory. It needs to be just in the `views` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it, it was just my project that was poorly structured
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anm56.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).